# Making picturebox appear when combobox element is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make pictures appear, when the element in combobox is selected.

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        pictureBox3.Visible = true;
        pictureBox4.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

I tried to do it this way, but that doesn't work. Where I’ve made the mistake?

Answer (score 4):

The naming of your method makes me think you're doing that inside the form loading event.

Use the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combobox instead.